# Uploading to newly created directory

Tags: php, mysql, session, mkdir, subdirectory

I have a directory called 'files' that contains folders that represent upload space for a user, e.g. `files/14` where '14' is the UserID of a user.

I am trying to create a simple script that when files are uploaded, the script:

- Checks if the User's folder already exists
- If user folder doesn't exist create one with the UserID, else ignore and continue
- Upload files to the newly created directory (e.g. 14) or upload in previously created user directory.

This is the code:

```
<?php 
    include("dbConfig.php");
    $Username = $_SESSION["username"];
    global $userid;
    $Password = $_SESSION["password"];
    $Password = md5($Password);

    $sql = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$Username."'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $userid = $row['UserID'];
    }

    $dirname =  (string)$userid;
    $filename = ("$dirname" . "/");

    if (!file_exists("../files/" .$filename)) {
        mkdir("files/$dirname", 0775);
    } else {
        if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
            echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";  
            foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
                $dest = ($filename . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest );
                echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The files are being uploaded into the root directory (../files), although the User Directory is being created.

Also, the warning is not being ignored, giving me this error:

```
**Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 80**
```

Can anyone help me and tell me how to fix this?

Comment: IMHO, I think you should stop using relative paths here. Use absolute paths instead.

Comment: dont use absolute paths ! never ! on windows, it works, on live websites, under linux, NOT ! because the url is absolute, it is seen as a non local address, and you wont be able to upload or save files

Answer (score 1):

How about using the same structure for both calls?

For example:

```
if (!file_exists("../files/" .$filename)) {
    mkdir("../files/" .$filename, 0775);
```

You seem to be checking that one file/folder exists on one hand and create another one somewhere else since `../files` != `files/`

Also navnav is right you should stop using relative paths. Garanteed problems down the road. Especially if you use some framework and url rewrinting.

Comment: thanks! the warning disappears, however, no files are uploaded :(

Comment: Then you probable have some paths problems. Very hard for use to help with that part. But normally move_uploaded_files needs a full path: c:\path\to\upload\to or /var/www/path/to/upload/to